# OpenCV-Python image processing, Type error

Tags: opencv

I am using the below mentioned code to track brown coloured magnetic beads. The line `cv2.circle(frame, center, 5 ,(0,0,255),-1)` is giving a Type error. Can anyone provide insight on this?

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import imutils

    black_lower = (0,0,0) #this two-blacks corresponds to the colour range in  hsv, which we are looking in ants
    black_upper = (130, 130, 128)
    kernel_erode = np.ones((1,1),np.uint8) #these kernels are defined for eroding and dialating image
    kernel_dialate = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
    r,h,c,w = 600, 400, 100, 700 # i have to play with the size of the window for getting the roi (currently cutting defined roi)
    track_window = (c,r,w,h)
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/idaho/Desktop/opencv_files/brown_beads.mp4')
    while (vid.isOpened()):
        ret,frame = vid.read()
        frame = imutils.resize(frame) #we have resized the frame, now we have to convert to hsv color space!
        hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV) # we have converted the frame in to hsv space!
        mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame,black_lower,black_upper)#now we should define a mask for color ranges from black_lower to black_upper and remove other noices!
        mask2 = cv2.erode(mask1,kernel_erode,iterations=1) #for increasing the object detection , we have to reduce the erode_kernel_size and increase the dialate_kernel_size
        mask3 = cv2.dilate(mask2,kernel_dialate,iterations=2)
        mask4 = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask3,(1,1),0)
        x,y,w,h = track_window # these are for defining the roi in the video, will have to play with this!
        cv2.rectangle(mask4,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        dst = np.zeros_like(mask4)
        dst[y:y+h,x:x+w] = mask4[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        cv2.imshow('gray',frame)
        #this is finding the specific object in the video and drawing a contour against it
        counts = cv2.findContours(mask4.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
        center = None
        if len(counts) > 0:
            calculate = max(counts,key = cv2.contourArea)
            ((x,y),radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(calculate)
            M = cv2.moments(calculate)
            center = (int(M["m10"]/M["m00"]),(M["m01"]/M["m00"]))
            if radius > 1:
                cv2.circle(frame, (int(x),int(y)),int(radius),(0,255,255),2)
                cv2.circle(frame, center, 5 ,(0,0,255),-1)
        pts.appendleft(center)
        for i in xrange(1,len(pts)):
            if pts[i-1] is None or pts[i] is None:
                continue
                thickness = int(np.sqrt(64/float(i+1))*2.5)
                cv2.line(frame,pts[i-1],pts[i],(0,0,255),thickness)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(50) and 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    vid.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Try printing this line `center = (int(M["m10"]/M["m00"]), (M["m01"]/M["m00"]))` and see if you get a non-zero value

Comment: Yes, I am getting non-zero integer values. center = (450,800.0)

Comment: The value (450, 800.0) has a float value. Convert it to type `int`, that is why you are getting the `Type error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Type error` occurs when the expected type of data is not fed. Any other type other than the expected type leads to this error.

You have to modify your line from:

`center = (int(M["m10"]/M["m00"]),(M["m01"]/M["m00"]))`

to:

`center = (int(M["m10"]/M["m00"]), int(M["m01"]/M["m00"]))`

You did not include type `int` to the second coordinate of the center, hence you have been receiving this error all the while.

Comment: Thanks luke! it worked. Now its giving me a NameError for pts.appendleft(center).

Comment: @marcosidaho What is the use of that line? I mean, what do you intend to use it for?

Comment: that line is used to append all the centroids of the blobs detected to the list  'pts'.

Comment: to append to pts use : `pts = np.append(center)`

Comment: Hi Luke, i had to define one more parameter along with the center to append the values to pts list. The code seems working, but am not able to track the object. Can you provide any insights in to this?

Comment: @marcosidaho I am unable to comment since I have nothing to visualize. Just make sure that your object of interest appears distinct for tracking, i.e, your pre-processing steps have to effective

Comment: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bc_OdLgGrPQ&feature=youtu.be"                                                           @Luke, this is the link for the video which i was tracking. I have to track the moving ants several times, i am not successful. Comments will be greatly appreciated,

Comment: @luke, can you provide any insights?

Comment: @marcosidaho I never came across such a problem before. Will get back if I get some ideas..